# aggregating categories in R

Tags: r, aggregate

Hi I'm new to R and I'm trying to aggregate a list and count the total but not sure how to do it.

```
myList =c("A", "B", "A", "A", "B")
```

I can create a function that loops through the list and groups each category and counts them. But I'm sure there must be an easier way to group this so that I can get the category and the number each category. That is A would be 3 and B would be 2.

I tried using the function below but I believe I don't have the proper syntax.

```
aggr <-aggregate(myList, count)
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm *guessing* that you're just looking for `table` and not actually `aggregate`:

```
myList =c("A", "B", "A", "A", "B")
table(myList)
# myList
# A B 
# 3 2
```

`tapply` can also be handy here:

```
tapply(myList, myList, length)
# A B 
# 3 2
```

And, I suppose you could "trick" `aggregate` in the following way:

```
aggregate(ind ~ myList, data.frame(myList, ind = 1), length)
#   myList ind
# 1      A   3
# 2      B   2
```

---

If you're looking to understand *why* as well, `aggregate` generally takes a `data.frame` as its input, and you specify one or more columns to be aggregated grouped by one or more other columns (or vectors in your workspace of the same length as the number of rows).

In the example above, I converted your vector into a `data.frame`, adding a dummy column where all the values were "1". I then used the formula `ind ~ myList` (where `~` is sort of like "is grouped by") and set the aggregation function to `length` (there is no `count` in base R, though that function can be found in different packages).